# Magento2 : How to call background image in PWA

Tags: css, magento2.3.1, pwa, pwa-studio

I have created one Static block and added below content in and need to add arrow above **TEST** text.

```
<li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
```

Like below image

[image]

Anyone have idea how can I add arrow using css in PWA Magento2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution

Create `images` folder under `src/components/CmsBlock/` add your image in `images` folder like `text.png`

Change in `test: /\.(jpg|svg)$/,` to `test: /\.(gif|svg|jpg|png)$/,` in `webpack.config.js` file.

Open `src/components/CmsBlock/cmsBlock.css` file and add below code in CSS file

```
background: url("./images/text.png") no-repeat left center;
```